# Which .Net Framework components can I remove from Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I want to update all our .Net Framework projects to the latest 4.8 version - currently they target a wide mix of 4.x versions. I noticed .Net Framework 4.8 wasn't actually offered as an option:
[image]

So I went to tidy up the VS installation - I would like to remove .Net < 4.8 components. I currently have this:
[image]

However whenever I try to untick any 4.x component I get a scary popup like those below, which doesn't look like something I want to do!
It gives the impression VS2019's components have hard links to specific 4.x framework versions?

I don't really understand the difference between a "targeting pack" and "SDK". I need to be able to develop .Net Framework 4.8, .Net Core 5.0 and .Net Standard (whatever the latest is) - which components can be removed if any?

4.6.1:
[image]

4.6:
[image]

4.5:
[image]